# Missing return statement in Java stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have the following list and map:

```
final List<Product> productList = productService.findAll(uuidList);

Map<UUID, Product> productMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to add the element pairs to the map as shown below:

```
productList.stream().map(product -> {
    productMap.put(product.getUuid(), product);
});
```

However, the last line throws "*Missing return statement*" error. When I update as shown below, it has gone, but this time return is useless. So, how should I add `UUID` and `Product` pair to my map?

Comment: Don’t use a stream, just `List.forEach()`. Like `productList.forEach(product -> productMap.put(product.getUuid(), product));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use `map` here, you can simply use `forEach`. The `map` method is intended to create another stream whose elements are "mapped" from the original stream.`forEach` just applies a consumer on each element, in this case the consumer is putting the element into a hash map.

```
productList.stream().forEach(product -> 
    productMap.put(product.getUuid(), product)
);
```

You can also simplify the code by using a map collector:

```
Map<UUID, Product> productMap = productList.stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getUuid, Function.identity()));
```

As for the reason why the original code with `map` is not compiling, it's because the `map` method expects a `Function` which by definition takes a value and returns something. Since you're using curly brackets, you should add a `return` statement. Alternatively you can remove the brackets, but keep in mind what I mentioned above, and that the return value is meaningless in this case since it's not used:

```
productList.stream().map(product -> 
    productMap.put(product.getUuid(), product);
);
```

Comment: Wonderful explanations, thanks a lot. On the other hand, sometimes the lambda methods are still work even if I add `stream()` or not. So, what is the effect of `stream()` exactly?

Comment: @Henry `List` also has a method `forEach` that accepts a consumer. The difference against `stream()` is that in general a stream allows for lazy evaluation. In your case it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @Could you please clarify a little bit more by giving an example when use `stream()` and not?

Comment: @Henry you use a Stream when you want to use at least one of the other features. In fact, `forEach` should be the least used Stream operation. Whereas for a `Collection`, it’s the only operation that happens to intersect with a `Stream` operation.